# Auto-overwrite leaderboard scores with Google Play Game Services?

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard

I'm trying to setup a GPGS leaderboard that tracks a user's win/loss ratio for a board game. The trouble is, the API automatically discards scores that don't "beat" the user's old score. This means a player could win their first game and stay at 100% on the leaderboard forever.

I've thought of adding multiple leaderboards for "Ratio after 10 games," "Ratio after 100 games," etc, which would require me to track their progress on my end and post only after 10 or 100 games are played, but I kind of like just having a single leaderboard for win ratio that kicks in after a certain number of games and live updates every game after.

Anyone know how to automatically overwrite the user's score without checking first to see if it's "better" than their current one?

Comment: This still sounds like a bad idea even if its doable... you will have users that only play 1 game and be at the top of the leaderboard forever. This makes the Leaderboard for "serious" players kinda pointless. Why not wait until Game 10 until you post the score for the first time ?

Comment: There is an outstanding request for an enhancement to the Google api that may be similar to this-support fir an elo ranking system which would necessitate the same type of update you are asking about. Please star the request to add weight to get it implemented.https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=12

Comment: thx for the heads up on the api request thread. until the feature is added, I'm just posting win ratios at 30, 100, and 1000 games to 3 different leaderboards. Basically, users will have three chances to rank on one of those leaderboards, and they'll be ranked with where everyone else was at that point.